# Matlab: webread is reading a subset of the data not all data

Tags: matlab, csv

I want to cluster a dataset records stored on a server using Matlab. I used `webread` to read the data from the server.

```
url1 = 'http://localhost:8011/contentC:/xqy/features_3sets.xqy';
url2 = 'http://localhost:8003/contentC:/xqy/features_3sets.xqy';

options = weboptions('Username','admin','Password','admin', 'ContentType','auto' , 'Timeout', 8000);

csv_data = webread(url1, options);
csv_testing= webread(url2, options);

%read data and convert to matrix
extracted_data=textscan(csv_data,'%s%s%s%s%s%s%s', 'delimiter',',');
attributes=[extracted_data{1} extracted_data{2} extracted_data{3}    extracted_data{4} extracted_data{5} extracted_data{6} extracted_data{7}];

extracted_testing=textscan(csv_testing,'%s%s%s%s%s%s%s', 'delimiter',',');
attributes_testing=[extracted_testing{1} extracted_testing{2}        extracted_testing{3} extracted_testing{4} extracted_testing{5}  extracted_testing{6} extracted_testing{7}];
```

I'm having a problem with the number of records returned by `webread`. The number of records saved on the server is **764**, while the number of records that were returned by `webread` is **382**. I need all records to be returned. NOTE: it seems like it is returning half of the data size **764/2=382**

Returned data:A single data record looks like this

```
plah plah ,nursg,low back pa risk factor staff,low back pa,low back pa risk factor staff,back pa risk factor epidemiology,plah,
```

I have printed `csv_data` I got this message at the end of the data `Output truncated.  Text exceeds maximum line length of 25,000 characters for Command Window display.`. Is it possible the there is a limit for reading data?

Comment: It's not json. It is in the form of csv. I have edited my question with adding a single record of the data. please have a look

Comment: At what point are you determining that you get too few records? I would count the number of newlines in `csv_data` to check.

Comment: I don't know how to do so. While I'm trying I have printed `csv_data` I got this message at the end of the data `Output truncated.  Text exceeds maximum line length of 25,000 characters for Command Window display.`. Is it possible the there is a limit for reading data?

Comment: You can count the number of entries using `numel(strsplit(csv_data, '\n'))`

Comment: the count of newlines is    383

Comment: the question still on?

Comment: YES, l'm stuck here

Comment: could you please try `websave()`instead of `webread()` and safe it directly? If this is not working you might have to split the request, but we could help with that. Also a data sample or maybe the data file would really help here

Comment: ok i checked some stuff: The `Output truncated. Text exceeds maximum line length of 25,000 characters for Command Window display.` has nothing to with all of this, this just happens when you try to print more than 25000 chars to the command window, but if you go for `csv_data(25001:end)` the correct values are still there. The issue is somewhere in the file and/or textscan. if you provide the `C:/xqy/features_3sets.xqy`we probably can fix this

Comment: @s.e What is actually generating this file? Have you considered that maybe the server isn't returning the entire file or is removing newline unnecessarily

Comment: @s.e may I suggest you upload those files on an online server (e.g. dropbox link) so that we may a) try out ourselves to see if it's something to do with the file and the commands you're using, and b) it may work fine online and the problem is with your webserver.

Comment: Try forcing the `ContentType` to `table`.    CSV records are delimited with newlines.   I assume you've tried simply cURLing the data to check what you actually have.   With `ContentType` of  `raw`  you can also see exactly what Matlab is trying to fetch.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this error.  I created 764 copies of the example record given and placed them a local file named _features_3sets.xqy_.  All 764 records are read using the code above.  Perhaps the data file itself has a problem or there is a constraint with the server architecture.